# What is the best way to convert WORD/PDF as site pages in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am having a work to convert WORD/PDF in to site pages in SharePoint.
WORD/PDF is having HTML contents such as TABLE, Picture.

When i am trying to convert WORD in to WEBPAGE and then copying the content and pasting in "CONTENT EDITOR" web part, I am loosing some of the styles.

Is there any other better way to implement this functionality?
Or else, Any SP webpart will help to achieve this?
Or we having any 3 party WebPart to have the WORD/PDF as content in SP?

Please provide your valuable suggestion????

Answer (score 10):

To converting Word file to web page there is a built in feature in SharePoint. Probably you already checked it out. But it works for me. So i am referring you the link.
[Convert-a-Word-document-to-a-Web-page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Convert-a-Word-document-to-a-Web-page-34079d7a-a6e4-43fd-b6a9-b7f4fd5c4585)

And for the styling issue, you can apply a CSS file to the Web page. Check out this  [Style](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-the-document-to-Web-page-converters-84bb310c-5539-437c-b92b-077e259984e7) , specifically in section 10 of this article to customize the CSS.

Comment: Is this functionality exists still in SharePoint 2013 ?

Comment: Yes. It exist in SharePoint 2013. But you have to start the service first. 
A details is here in this [post](http://www.kaboodlekonnect.com/colin/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=19) which describes how to start the service. Hope it will help.